# What version of Exchange am I running?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

A server I've recently taken charge of has a copy of Exchange installed.  Add or Remove Programs just shows "Microsoft Exchange".  By clicking on Change/Remove I can see that the version number is 6.5, which [is the version number for](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158530) Exchange 2003.

How do I find out if I'm running Standard, Enterprise or something else, though?

Additional facts:

- The server is running Windows Server 2003.
- The version hasn't been documented anywhere and there's nobody I can ask

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Exchange System Manager, go to the `Servers` folder and click the folder so the servers appear in the right pane. In the `Edition` column should be the server version.

[image: Exchange Server 2003 Edition]

Comment: Can't believe I didn't stumble across that..!  Thanks, anyway :)